# geom_text removing other geoms (geom_point and geom_line)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some strange behavior with a dataset I am working with. I plot a points layer and then I plot a line layer, and then i look to plot a subset of labels. But the labels are removing the line and points layers. I can't replicate the problem in another data set and cannot workout what is going on.

Here is the code that is giving the problem:

```
#Have a look at the data:
>head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  p.start p.end  year  value change
    <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1       0     1  2017 -4928.  1144.
2       1     2  2017     0   -798.
3       2     3  2017   687. -3400.
4       3     4  2017  3438. -3063.
5       4     5  2017  5978. -2400.
6       5     6  2017  7988. -2023.

>tail(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  p.start p.end  year    value  change
    <dbl> <dbl> <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1    96      97  2017  208759.  23221.
2    97      98  2017  248919.  28333.
3    98      99  2017  334171.  36818.
4    99     100  2017 1104671. 113244.
5    99.5   100  2017 1709530. 174812.
6    99.9   100  2017 4847340. 504441 

#Create the relevant plot
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(df, aes(x = p.start, y = change)) +
  geom_point() + #plot the points and lines
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data = subset(df, p.start >= 99), #plot a subset labels
            aes(x = p.start, y = value, label = p.start))
```

[image]

You can see the `geom_text()` removing the `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`. I tried 'nudge_x' but that didn't make a difference. I also tried plotting the layers in a different order by that didn't make a difference.

I try and do this with a different dataset and it works:

```
library('tibble')
#set rownames to use as labels
df2 <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('name')

#plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + 
  geom_point() + #plot the points and lines
  geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data = subset(df, cyl > 4), #plot a subset of labels
            aes(x = mpg, y = hp, label = name))
```

[image]

Things work fine: The labels appear over the points and lines.

What is wrong with my first plot/data that is causing this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  Your code works as expected.

Comment: It looks like you're using `aes(y=change)` for the points and line, and `y=value` for the text. `value` has bigger values than `change`, so makes the `change` axis look flat.

Comment: @Alexlok: correct! Silly oversight. Having the y set to the correct variable in each case makes things work. Apologies for the confusion.